# Delete big chunk of data with where clause gives time-out

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to delete over 2 millions records with this statement

```
DELETE FROM `table` where event_tstamp<1612212312
```

And I get 504 error time-out, when I try the same statement with select instead of delete it works, there is an index on event_tstamp column. Any idea what could be the problem?

Comment: try to add a LIMIT in your DELETE, for example: DELETE FROM `table` where event_tstamp<1612212312 LIMIT 200000

Comment: Are you saying when you run this from PHP it gets the timeout?

Comment: I tried from php script and in directly in phpmyadmin and I get time error out on both occasions

Comment: With limit is working so I guess I can do loop in php

Comment: Create and execute stored procedure which deleted by chunks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`delete` is a much more expensive operation than `select`.  The deletes have to be logged, for instance, and all take place in the context of a transaction.

One work-around is to create a new table, empty the current one, and reload:

```
create table temp_table as
    select t.*
    from `table` t
    where event_tstamp >= 1612212312;

truncate table `table`;

insert into `table`
    select *
    from temp_table;
```

It turns out that inserting into a table is often faster than deleting rows.

Note:  This requires special consideration if your table has triggers or auto-incremented columns.  You can also do what Akina suggests and batch the deletes.  If you don't want to write a stored procedure, just keep running something like:

```
DELETE FROM `table` 
    WHERE event_tstamp < 1612212312
    LIMIT 10000;  -- or whatever convenient batch size you want
```

until no rows are deleted.

If this is the type of operation you need to perform periodically, then you probably want to use [table partitioning](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/partitioning.html).  Dropping a partition is much, much faster than deleting rows individually.

Answer (score 1):

You may use (in CLI):

```sql
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE PROCEDURE delete_by_chunks ()
BEGIN
REPEAT
    DELETE FROM `table` where event_tstamp<1612212312 LIMIT 10000;
    UNTIL ROW_COUNT() END REPEAT;
END;;
DELIMITER ;

CALL delete_by_chunks;

DROP PROCEDURE delete_by_chunks;
```

Adjust LIMIT parameter to reasonable value.